# how to get all agents with phrets

Tags: php, rets

I am trying to fetch all MLS agents using phrets, but everything I try returns nothing.

The goal of this is to be able to get more info about a salesperson of an MLS listing.

```
# Search query
$search = $rets->SearchQuery("roster","Agent","*");
```

If that is not possible, is there any way how I can figure out all available fields for that class?

Comment: If you are a vendor/developer, you most likely do not have access to the agents table in your data feed. I'm a vendor for a MLS and we do not have access to that data as it is restricted.

Comment: Hey!
I was able to get additional information by looking up each agent of a listing by e-mail address (we do have access to their phone number, website, e-mail address and full name) - see the accepted answer and its comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enter in your RETS login information into [RETS M.D.](http://retsmd.com) and it will return all metadata and fields for each class (ResidentialProperty, Agent, etc).

If you want to get the listing agent's information for a specific MLS listing and you have the MLS ID, it would be something like this:

```
    $mlsNumber = 130050044;

    //Perform search query for a specific MLS Id
    $search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property", "9", "(MLNumber_f139={$mlsNumber})", array('Limit' => 1, 'Format' => 'COMPACT'));

    $numRows = $rets->NumRows();

    if ($numRows > 0) {

        $listing = $rets->FetchRow($search);
        // Get Agent's public Id from MLS listing
        $agentId = $listing['ListingPublicID_f1187'];

        // Perform search query for Agent using Agent Id
        $search = $rets->SearchQuery("User", "14", "(AgentPublicID_f1191={$agentId})", array('Limit' => 1, 'Format' => 'COMPACT'));
        $numRows = $rets->NumRows();

        if ($numRows > 0) {
            $listing = $rets->FetchRow($search);
            $agentName = $listing['AgentFullName_f1595'];
            echo "Agent Name : " . $agentName . "<br />";
            // echo more Agent Details here
        }

    }

    $rets->FreeResult($search);
```

If you wanted to run a search query to return all Agents from a RETS Server, your DMQL might search for all agents with a status of Active.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow, thanks.
But what exactly do you mean with "login into RETS M.D."? What is the RETS MD?

Comment: Thank you. I don't really have the agent's public ID, but my listings contain the agent's e-mail address. With that, I can search the agent.
RETS MD seems to be a very handy tool!

Answer (score 1):

To figure out all available fields of a class, use

```
$fields = $rets->SearchGetFields($search);
```